# NodeJS: request piping cloudfront returns binary but not showing image

Tags: node.js, request

I have strange problem. I am piping image from S3/Cloudfront. The image is shown ok when put inside img-tag but not directly when opening in browser.

For example this kind of url:

http://localhost:3000/cdn/storage/MyFiles/vBPB27yfHESZfRkCs/original/vBPB27yfHESZfRkCs.jpg

is piped (fake url below)

```
const url = "https://d28crSOMETHING.cloudfront.net/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJjYXJhd2F5ZXVyb3BlIiwia2V5Ijoic2FsZXNhZHMvd1c3c25iU2I0SmJTUHB4amovVHZaakpUa2hvTkVTN04yc1IuDFanBnIiwiZWRpdHMiOnsicmVzaXplIjp7IndpZHRoIjozMDAwLCJmaXQiOiJvdXRzaWRlIn1=="

request(url).pipe(http.response);
```

http.response is middleware request instance in https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files

- Chrome shows image like this
  [image]
- Firefox shows image
- Internet Explorer 11 tries to download file. Saved file is correct
- Edge tries to download file. Saved file is correct

What cloud cause this? Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Try setting response header Content-Type: 'image/png'  something like : http.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');

Comment: Thanks. I have tried. Chrome says contentype is 'image' :/

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet how http.response object is being created?

Comment: Just a moment. Btw, i think this is related somehow AWS Serverless image handler https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/serverless-image-handler/ because if I pipe any other image url, it works directly ..

Comment: yup makes sense.